# Local saving user credentials after registration in fabric-ca

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, npm, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Help me please!
How can I save user credentials in special local folder after registration in fabric-ca?
I write app with npm packages for hyperledger fabric.

```
let wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(path)
```

This code not work for me, because I use special platform on isolated k8s cluster and write code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line of code is correct. It you execute it locally, the wallet will be saved on your local desktop within the path specified in the `path` variable.

If the code is being executed within a container, the same applies. You may want to use a PVC mounted to have persistent storage for the wallet. Otherwise, the wallet will be created within the container, and will be recreated each time the container is restarted.

Now, If you mean to have the code executed on an isolated platform and wish to have them stored on your local machine, you will need to setup a bridge within the isolated platform and your desktop. But that isn't a fabric related issue. It has more to do with how you setup your development environment. (network, storage, port-forwarding, and so forth).